# Get associative array after post via ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

I need to send a form and a array/string to the server.

My Ajax looks like this:

```
 var formData = $("#formpv").serialize();
        $.ajax({    
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'scripts/formIntoDB.php',
            data: formData,
```

In this way I can retrieve the form data in PHP like this:

```
$_POST['name'];
//Output "Foobar"
```

But when I send the the serialized formdata and another param like this:

```
 var formData = $("#formpv").serialize();
 var posData = "TEST";

        $.ajax({    
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'scripts/formIntoDB.php',
            data: {form: formData, pos: posData},
```

And try to get name now in PHP:

```
$_POST['form']['name'];
```

This just throws *PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['*

Whats the difference when I send the data like this  data:
*{form: formData, pos: posData}* and
*data: formData* ?

Comment: You have a syntax error, show the real code, not just excerpt which is obviously correct.

Comment: This is the whole code. The php is just <?php error_log($_POST['form']['name]);

Comment: `serialize` creates a form-urlencoded representation of your data. So basically your request body would contain `name=foo&bar=baz`, for two parameters `name` and `bar`, and their respective values. But with your second variant, you would be sending `form=name%3Dfoo%26bar%3Dbaz&pos=...`. The actual _value_ of `form` now is `name=foo&bar=baz`. PHP does not resolve two "levels" of query string encoding, only one.

Comment: It still does not explain syntax error.

Comment: If `<?php error_log($_POST['form']['name]);` is your actual code, then you have a syntax error there; you're missing the closing `'` for the `name`. Is the code you've posted (both in the question and the comment) a proper copy/paste or a rewrite here?

Comment: The closing ' is there. Just wrote this by hand. Not caopy and pasted it. But the explanation for my problem is already given by Rory.

Comment: If you get a syntax error, please copy/paste the actual code. If you rewrite the code, you might very well accidentally fix the issue or create other issues. I do see that you've now accepted the below answer, but I don't see how it would solve your syntax error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because the string in `formData` becomes double-wrapped, ie. a string of key/value pairs within a string of key/value pairs. As only the top level of this is deserialised, your PHP code cannot read the second level in the manner you intend.

To fix this you either need to *manually* create the entire object, eg:

```
$.ajax({    
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'scripts/formIntoDB.php',
  data: {
    form: {
      name: $('#yourNameInput').val(),
      // all your other inputs here...
    }, 
    pos: posData
  }
});
```

Or you instead could keep the request data flat and just add `pos` using a hidden input within the form.